# What are the rules associated with the ritual of kshoura/kshavaram (shaving of hair)? And do these differ between sampradayas?

Tags: rituals, tradition, dharma-shastras, customs

Almost all samparadayas and communities have some set of rules associated with the kshoura karma. There are rules related not just to the days on which such activities can be performed but also related to the shape and size of the shikha, sarvanga, rules for kshoura during apara karma etc. These vary significantly between communities within the same sampradaya or tradition.

It would good to compile here as to What are those standards and wherefrom are they cited.

Comment: Compiling a list is a hectic work and it is a list question. Such questions are generally discouraged on Stack Exchange network. They are closed as closed as too broad. They will go on increase. Please avoid asking for list or compilation of rules in a place. That compilation will be the same as copying from other books. So, that would not be that useful.

Comment: Aren't most answers here compiled references from books and other sources? Esp. given that subjective or even experience based answers are also deemed unacceptable? The scope might be broad for one person, yes. But individually, one can cover their tradition and still leave room for others to cover theirs. If this has to be closed, so be it. But I do believe the question is justified.